# confuse about EndUploadFromStream

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am confusing with a problem about upload blobs asynchronously, hopes find answer here.

Please take a look at my code snippet first,

```
public void UploadMultipleBlobs(List<string> filelocations, string containerName, AsyncCallback callback = null, string path = null)
    {
                    try
        {

            Parallel.ForEach(filelocations, fileLocation =>
                {

                    //File to Stream
                    MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
                    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileLocation);
                    str.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
                    str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    //Operations
                    if (callback == null)
                        callback = new AsyncCallback(OnUploadCompleted);
                    BlobRequestOptions blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
                    blobRequestOptions.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
                    blobRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = retry;

                    CloudBlob currentBlob = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
                    var result = currentBlob.BeginUploadFromStream(str, blobRequestOptions, callback, new Object[] { currentBlob, str });

                    currentBlob.EndUploadFromStream(result);
                });

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

    }

private void OnUploadCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get array passed to callback
            Object[] states = (Object[])result.AsyncState;

            var blob = (CloudBlob)states[0];
            var stream = (MemoryStream)states[1];

            // End the operation
            //blob.EndUploadFromStream(result);

            // Close the stream
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I need to upload mutil files to Azure blob, number of files may be 10-50,000, each file is about 10KB-50KB. The code snippet works fine for me currently. However, if I call EndUploadFromStream in callback, it always throw an exception when uploading over 2,000 files. I mean if I remove EndUploadFromStream in upload method and call EndUploadFromStream  in callback(OnUploadCompleted method), the exception happens. The exception message as below:

Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed., StackTrace: at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()

at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob.EndUploadFromStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

I don't know why it happens...hopes got answer from you guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Begin/End code looks OK. I notice that you're not doing anything to wait for the asynchronous operations to complete, so the problem may be related to that. eg, if you're running this from a console application then the application may exit before all the uploads have completed and then give you those errors. That would not be a problem if the `EndUploadFromStream()` call is inside the `Parallel.ForEach()` because it will cause the `Parallel.ForEach()` call to block until all the uploads have completed.

So try adding code to wait for all the uploads to complete and see if that fixes it. A simple way would be a counter that is initialized to the total number of uploads, and then decremented (using `Interlocked.Decremement()` for thread safety) inside of the callback. Another options would be use `Task.FromAsync()` to get an array of Task objects, then using `Task.WaitAll()` to wait for them to complete.

As an aside, using both `Parallel.ForEach()` and Begin/End methods at the same time is usually redundant - Begin/End is asynchronous already so there's usually no point using multiple threads to invoke it. Since you have such a big list of items it *might* make some difference in this case, but probably not much. You're probably better off using a simple `foreach` loop instead of `Parallel.ForEach()` unless you've actually measured a significant difference.